# How can I prepend/append the results of all function calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, append, prepend

Lets say I have a function

`function sum(...args) {
   return args.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0)
 }`

and I am using it like this ->

`console.log( “hi ” +  sum(2,3) + “ hello” )` which would give me the output `hi 5 hello`

I want to achieve the result 
`hi start 5 end hello`

Basically, I want to append and prepend some fixed values to every output of the function call, irrespective of the function itself.

I have tried overriding the valueOf property but it doesn't work

NOTE: `sum` is just an example function. Is there some solution possible so that it works with all functions?

Comment: You want to append and prepend something to every function? Or just this function?

Comment: Yes I want to append and prepend something to every function

Comment: EVERY function in your code?

Comment: Yes, every function in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a prototype and use it to call your functions, and include whatever you want inside of it:

```js
Function.prototype.debug = function(...args){
    let res = this.apply(this, args);
    console.log("Called function '" + this.name + "'. Result: start " + res + " end");
    return res;
}

function sum(...args) {
   return args.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0)
}

console.log( "hi " +  sum.debug(2,3) + " hello");
```

Comment: This is a similar approach to currying. I can't modify each and every function call

Comment: I tried to look for a way to hook every function call using `Function.prototype.valueOf` but it doesn't get called every time. There's no other way that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it for loggin purposes:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return a/b;
}

const oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function(msg) {
  oldLog(`start ${msg} end`);
}

console.log(sum(1,2));
console.log(divide(1,2));
```

Comment: That would append and prepend the whole console.log output
I only want to append/prepend only the function responses